# Почему запускается такая портянка запросов?

Tags: angular2, angular

Есть некая форма:

```
<form [formGroup]="testSettingsForm" (ngSubmit)="getTestInfo(testSettingsForm.value)">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Система</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="system">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let sys of systemInfo"
                  [value]="sys.id"
                  (onSelectionChange)="getSystemVersion(sys.id);"
                  (click)="getSystemVersion(sys.id);">
        {{sys.description}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Версия</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="systemVersion">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let version of systemVersion"
                  [value]="version.id"
                  (onSelectionChange)="getTestType(version.system_id, version.id)"
                  (click)="getTestType(version.system_id, version.id)">
        {{version.description}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Вид теста</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="testType">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let type of testType"
                  [value]="type.id" (onSelectionChange)="getTestNumber(type.system_id, type.version_id, type.id)"
                  (click)="getTestNumber(type.system_id, type.version_id, type.id)">
        {{type.description}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Номер теста</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="testNumber">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let nums of testNumber"
                  [value]="nums.test_number">
        {{nums.test_number}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>

  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">Загрузить</button>
</form>
```

Есть несколько функций, который отправляют запросы на бэк при изменении и при клике на опции.

```
getSystemFullInfo() {
this.repSrvc.getSystemName()
  .subscribe(
    res => {
      this.systemInfo = res;
      this.testSettingsForm.controls.system.setValue(res[0].id);
      this.repSrvc.getTestResult(this.testSettingsForm.value).subscribe(result => {
        this.testFullInfo.next(result);
      });
    }
      );
  }
  getSystemVersion(systemId): any {
    this.repSrvc.getSystemVersion(systemId)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          this.systemVersion = res;
          this.testSettingsForm.controls.systemVersion.setValue(res[0].id);
        }
      );
  }


  getTestType(systemId, versionId): any {
    this.repSrvc.getTestType(systemId, versionId)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          this.testType = res;
          this.testSettingsForm.controls.testType.setValue(res[0].id);
        }
      );
  }

  getTestNumber(systemId, versionId, testType): any {
    this.repSrvc.getTestNumber(systemId, versionId, testType)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          this.testNumber = res;
          this.testSettingsForm.controls.testNumber.setValue(res[0].test_number);
        }
      );
  }

  getTestInfo(formData): any {
    console.log(this.testSettingsForm.value);
    this.testInfo = formData;
  }

  constructor(
    private repSrvc: ReportingService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getSystemFullInfo();
  }
```

Почему при инициализации приложения отправляется вот такая портянка из http запросов?
[image: портянка]

Answer (score 2):

При использвании метода .setValue() передавай вторым параметром {emitEvent: false} вот так: setValue(value, {emitEvent: false}), тогда методы которые детектят изменения не будут реагировать и создавать повторные запросы.
Или в подписке на изменения используй метод .distinctUntilChanged(), чтобы не дублировать запросы на повторяющиеся значения:

```
form.valueChanges.pipe(
 distinctUntilChanged()
).subscribe()
```

Comment: с эмитом правильный вариант